# Execute a special for loop

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a array:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I need to perform a for loop on this array where at each number I need to add +90, and -90

now here the issue:

in a normal for loop the code will be like this:

```
for i in array {

let plus = i + 90
append.newArray(plus)
let minus = i - 90
append.newArray(plus)
}
```

I need to switch the plus and minus..
at the first cycle I need to append to the newArray plus and minus..... but for the second cycle  I must append in order minus and plus.

is there any way to switch the for loop to alternate between the plus and minus -- minus plus.

Comment: What do you mean by the first cycle and second cycle? It for iteration? like +, -, -, + ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it, as I understand, for odd and even values in source array, so you can use something like this:

```swift
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var newArray: [Int] = []

func plusValue(_ value: Int) {
    let plus = value + 90
    newArray.append(plus)
}

func minusValue(_ value: Int) {
    let minus = value - 90
    newArray.append(minus)
}

for (value, index) in array.enumerated() {
    if index.isMultiple(of: 2) { // even
        minusValue(value)
        plusValue(value)
    } else { // odd
        plusValue(value)
        minusValue(value)
    }
}
```

Just need to understand what you need to use for even and for odd indexies.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it using a for loop over the indices

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5]
var output = [Int]()

for index in array.indices {
    let value = index % 2 == 0 ? 90 : -90
    output.append(array[index] + value)
    output.append(array[index] - value)
}
```

another option is to use `reduce(into:)`

```
let output = array.enumerated().reduce(into: []) { 
    let factor = $1.offset % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1
    $0.append(contentsOf: [$1.element + factor * 90, $1.element - factor * 90])
}
```

Comment: If the array is not an Int.. ? I have have try to simplify for explanation.. but actually the array is an array of CL location

Comment: It should be basically the same although the code is maybe a bit longer depending on what you want to do and because it's a more complex type than Int.

Comment: `index.isMultiple(of: 2)`

Comment: @DamianoMiazzi Since you asked about an Int array we use an Int array in our answers so you need to accept that and then apply your real type yourself to the given answers